# In what ways does the current FAA written exam differ from the Sporty's practice test?

Tags: faa, ppl

I am preparing to take my PPL written exam. I have been using the Sporty's practice exam program to gauge my progress? Recently I heard that the FAA has changed a few things about the tests. So I am curios: How the current written exam differs from the Sporty's practice exam?

1. Does the current written exam use the Airman Knowledge Testing Supplement for Sport Pilot, Recreational Pilot and Private Pilot?
2. Are the questions formatted in the same way as the practice question?
3. If you perform well with the Sporty's practice exam with an actual understanding of how you got to your answer, would you likely do well with the current test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took the PPL written exam this morning (9/30/2016), but I used the Jeppesen PPL materials to prepare. Although I cannot speak to the Sporty's study materials, the Jeppesen practice exam and supporting materials were identical to the questions on the real exam. I would assume that Sporty's will be (almost?) the same. I actually scored higher on the real exam than on any of the practice tests.

Yes, the current exam uses the Airman Knowledge Testing Supplement for Sport Pilot, Recreational Pilot and Private Pilot booklet.